# Multithreaded Downloading Through Proxies In Python

Tags: python, proxy, download, multithreading, harvest

What would be the best library for multithreaded harvesting/downloading with multiple proxy support? I've looked at Tkinter, it looks good but there are so many, does anyone have a specific recommendation? Many thanks!

Comment: multithreaded for many files, or many pieces of one file?

Comment: many files simultaneously downloading and adding new files when threads are free

Answer (score 1):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you can't just do by passing a URL to newly spawned threads and calling urllib2.urlopen in each one, or is there a more specific requirement?

Comment: urllib2 isn't thread safe from what I've seen, but I could of just been doing it wrong because I'm a noob to threading. I am downloading a lot of files so I'd rather use something a bit more powerful than just urllib anyway

Comment: It's almost certain to be thread-safe unless you do something inherently dangerous like trying to access the same object from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at http://scrapy.org/, which is a scraping framework built on top of twisted.

Comment: Excellent, I don't see anything about proxy support but I think I could do that myself.

Comment: No. Support for HTTP proxies is not currently implemented in Scrapy, but it will be in the future. For more information about this, follow this ticket. Setting the http_proxy environment variable won’t work because Twisted (the library used by Scrapy to download pages) doesn’t support it. See this Twisted ticket for more info.